# Group by one column and substring of its own

Tags: sql

Unable to write a Sql for my problem.
I have a table with 2 columns item code and expiration date.

```
Itemcode.       Expiration
Abc123.         2014-08-08
Abc234.         2014-07-07
Cfg345.         2014-06-06
Cfg567.         2014-07-08
```

The output should be based on first 3 digits of item code and minimum expirarion date like below

```
Abc.     2014-07-07.    Abc234
Cfg.     2014-06-06.    Cfg345
```

Thanks

EDITED:
The query goes like this which actually is joining multiple tables to fetch the itemcode and expiration.
    select      substr(y.itemcode,1,3), 
                              min(x.expiration_date) expiry, 
                              y.itemcode
                              from X x, Y y
                              where y.id = x.id

```
                          and x.number  in 
                              (select number from xyz 
                                where id = x.id
                                and codec in ('C', 'M', 'T', 'H')

                               ) 

                               group by substr(y.itemcode,1,3), y.itemcode
```

Comment: Show your code. What did you try already?

Comment: I am not able to figure out. I used group by clause but i need both the substring and the item code so using group by doesnt help. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with "m".  Here is an ANSI standard SQL solution:

```
select substring(itemcode, 1, 3), expiration, itemcode
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by substring(itemcode, 1, 3)
                                order by expiration desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Most databases support this functionality.  Some might have slightly different names (such as `substr()` or `left()` for the substring operation).

Comment: HI Gordon I have modified my question and provided the exact query. I need your help there since I am unable to put it there. It joins 2 tables to fetch the data. Please help.